# AirFlow sends exception wrapped with HTTP 200 OK

Tags: airflow, airflow-api

When we call a DAG using REST, the AirFlow tries to execute it but if there is an exception it sends back the stack trace as a response body wrapped with HTTP 200 OK.

How can we change that feature so that if there is any execution error, it would rather send 400 error?

Answer (score 0):

This is [the intended behavior](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dag_run), assuming that you're using the 'get DAG run' endpoint. You should reference the `state` field that is returned.